# screenlog in multiple files

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to log multiple output of serial lines with screen. I use the following:

```
screen -L /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
screen -L /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Screen logs the output in ONE single file `screenlog.0` instead of two `screenlog.X` files.

The nodes are hanging on a server. I use screen and within screen the first command above. Then I open a further screen-window and start the second command.
I didn't find any hint via Google.

Comment: What indication do you have that it would do `screenlog.X`?

Comment: @mikeserv: the output of both nodes were logged to `screenlog.0` but I want the output to two different files f.e. `screenlog.0` and `screenlog.1` for further analysis. The X in `screenlog.X` is only a place holder.

Answer (score 0):

The number in the logfile refers to the pseudoterminal number. It is possible to do `Ctrl-a N` for the second command which should detach to pseudoterminal N and save as `screenlog.N`.

In screen V4.06.02 and later you can add the `-Logfile` option to specify the logfile name, e.g.

```
screen -L -Logfile screenlog.1 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Also you could just get rid of the `-L` argument, and redirect the output:

```
screen -L /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 >& logfile.1
```